# Align to top of box

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsmath

This latex code (uses amsmath and proof) produces the image below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{proof}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \infer[\forall x \mathrm{i}]{\forall x \phi}{%
    \boxed{x_0 \quad \mbox{\infer*{\phi\lbrack x_0/x \rbrack}{}}}
  }
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: wrong alignment]

How can I make the x_0 align to the top of the \boxed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reference point of an `\infer` box is at the bottom. You can change its vertical alignment with `adjustbox`; I show three versions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,proof,adjustbox,calc}

\begin{document}
\[
\infer[\forall x \mathrm{i}]
  {\forall x \phi}
  {%
   \boxed{
     x_0
     \quad
     \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t,raise=-.6ex}
       \infer*{\phi[x_0/x]}{}
     \end{adjustbox}
   }%
  }
\qquad
\infer[\forall x \mathrm{i}]
  {\forall x \phi}
  {%
   \boxed{
     x_0
     \quad
     \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
       \infer*{\phi[x_0/x]}{}
     \end{adjustbox}
   }%
  }
\qquad
\infer[\forall x \mathrm{i}]
  {\forall x \phi}
  {%
   \boxed{
     x_0
     \quad
     \begin{adjustbox}{valign=T}
       \infer*{\phi[x_0/x]}{}
     \end{adjustbox}
   }%
  }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]